# trigger after insert on table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

```
create or replace
trigger addpagamento
after insert on marcacoes_refeicoes
for each row
declare 
  nmarcacaoa number;
  ncartaoa number;
begin

  select nmarcacao into nmarcacaoa from marcacoes_refeicoes where rownum < (select count(*) from marcacoes_refeicoes);
  select ncartao into ncartaoa from marcacoes_refeicoes where rownum < (select count(*) from marcacoes_refeicoes);
  insert_pagamentos(nmarcacaoa, ncartaoa); --this is a procedure

  exception when others then
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'Error in Trigger!!!');

end addpagamento;
```

when i try to run the insert statement to the table "marcacoes_refeicoes" this procedure gives error: like the table is mutating

```
create or replace
procedure insert_pagamentos 
(nmarcacaoa in number, ncartaoa in number)
AS 
BEGIN
  insert into pagamentos (nmarcacao, datapagamento, ncartao) values (nmarcacaoa, sysdate, ncartaoa);
  commit;
END INSERT_PAGAMENTOS;
```

Comment: what does this `insert_pagamentos` function do? If it's doing its own insert/update/delete queries on the table, that's a mutation.

Comment: its a procedure which is going to insert data in other table, not the same

Comment: Then you might have a trigger on the other table that does an update, or even a select, on the first one? Or the procedure itself accesses the first table? Basically you can't access the table that has the trigger, because its state is undefined during trigger execution. Check the examples in the link i posted to see how to get around that. We can't write your code for you, especially since you didn't post the insert_pagamentos procedure.

Comment: i've inserted the procedure, but i how can i do it?
im new at pl sql, sorry

Comment: What are trying to get into the two variables? Querying the table you're inserting (which you can't) like that looks weird anyway. What are you trying to get, the values form the previously inserted row (also wrong), or the row being inserted now? If the latter then you can refer to the current row with `:new`?

Comment: as i said, i'm new at this, and this was the way i thougth would be the best, now i dont know what to do!

Comment: @Severiano - but what are you actually trying to do? Do you want the same values in both tables? Is `pagamentos` like an audit table, or similar?

Answer (score 1):

Short (oversimplified) answer:

You can't modify a table in a trigger that changes the table.

Long answer:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/mutating-table-exceptions.php has a more in-depth explanation, including suggestions how to work around the problem.

Comment: how can i solve this then, i need to insert data in other table after the last one has entered a new row

Comment: i need to use triggers

Comment: In Oracle 11 you can use compount triggers, i.e. you don't have to define a separate package for it.

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting the mutating-table problem because you're selecting from the same table the trigger is on, but what you seem to be trying to do doesn't make sense. Your queries to get a value for `nmarcacaoa` and `ncartaoa` will return a `no_data_found` or `too_many_rows` error unless the table had exactly 2 rows in it before your insert:

```
select nmarcacao from marcacoes_refeicoes
where rownum < (select count(*) from marcacoes_refeicoes);
```

will return all rows except one; and the one that's excluded will be kind of random as you have no ordering. Though the state is undetermined within the trigger, so you can't really how many rows there are, and it won't let you do this query anyway. You won't normally be able to get a single value, anyway, and it's not obvious which value you actually want.

I can only imagine that you're trying to use the values from the row you are currently inserting, and putting them in your separate payments (`pagamentos`) table. If so there is a built-in mechanism to do that using [correlation names](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955), which lets you refer to the newly inserted row as `:new` (by default):

```
create or replace
trigger addpagamento
after insert on marcacoes_refeicoes
for each row
begin
  insert_pagamentos(:new.nmarcacaoa, :new.ncartaoa);
end addpagamento;
```

The `:new` is referring to the current row, so `:new.nmarcacaoa` is the `nmarcacaoa` being inserted. You don't need to (and can't) get that value from the table itself. (Even with the suggested autonomous pragma, that would be a separate transaction and would not be able to see your  newly inserted and uncommitted data).

Or you can just do the insert directly; not sure what the procedure is adding here really:

```
create or replace
trigger addpagamento
after insert on marcacoes_refeicoes
for each row
begin
  insert into pagamentos(nmarcacao, datapagamento, ncartao)
  values (:new.nmarcacaoa, sysdate, :new.ncartaoa);
end addpagamento;
```

I've removed the exception handler as all it was doing was masking the real error, which is rather unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

Editing this answer in view of the comments below:

You can use PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION to get rid of the error, but DONOT USE it as it will NOT solve any purpose.

Use PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION:

```
create or replace
trigger addpagamento
after insert on marcacoes_refeicoes
for each row
declare 
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  nmarcacaoa number;
  ncartaoa number;
begin

  select nmarcacao into nmarcacaoa from marcacoes_refeicoes where rownum < (select count(*) from marcacoes_refeicoes);
  select ncartao into ncartaoa from marcacoes_refeicoes where rownum < (select count(*) from marcacoes_refeicoes);
  insert_pagamentos(nmarcacaoa, ncartaoa); --this is a procedure

  exception when others then
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'Error in Trigger!!!');

end addpagamento;
```

However in this case , `select count(*) from marcacoes_refeicoes` will give you the new count after the current insertion into the table.

Comment: Don't do this, please. [This not a valid workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248569/i-have-a-trigger-autonomous-but-only-execute-one-time-in-the-same-session).

Comment: Thanks @VincentMalgrat . I only knew it theoretically, so didnt know its applications.